# Question in discrete mathematics *

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, extremal-combinatorics

I have question. Can anyone able to explain to me this problem why if we have 5x the generating function $1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15} + \ldots$
we have 5 is just constant and multiply with $x$ I know that $x$ we can write as geometric series but how we get this generating function just from information given is $5x$
but how we change 5x to this series this part i want explain 
thanks

Comment: $5$ isn't multiplied by $x$ anywhere in that series. It is unclear what you are trying to say here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the series for $\frac{1}{1 - x^5}$.